# How to get instance of AndroidManifest in Robolectric 3.5.1?

Tags: android, robolectric

[`DefaultPackageManager`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.4/org/robolectric/res/builder/DefaultPackageManager.html) was deprecated in 3.4 of robolectric. We used reflection to get an instance of [`AndroidManifest`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.4/org/robolectric/manifest/AndroidManifest.html) from `DefaultPackageManager`. In version 3.5.1, how can I get the currently valid instance of `AndroidManifest` while under test?

Comment: Have you tried normal PackageManager?

Comment: normal `PackageManager` doesn't yet support the APIs yet that I need in robolectric.

Answer (score 0):

normal `PackageManager` doesn't yet support the APIs yet that I need in robolectric. Until then, `RuntimeEnvironment.getAndroidManifest()` will work.